# Perché il suffisso '-accia/-accio' connota negativamente le parole cui viene aggiunto?

Tags: etymology, suffix

Credo che il suffisso *-accia* / *-accio* sia usato sempre per connotare negativamente qualcosa, per esempio: *roba* e *robaccia*, *parola* e *parolaccia*, *donna* e *donnaccia* e così via.

Sapreste indicare quali siano le origini storiche che hanno determinato questa funzione per il suffisso in questione?

Inoltre, si usa solo per trasformare i sostantivi o anche gli aggettivi?

Comment: Secondo me da più una connotazione di qualcosa di grezzo,rude  certamente non positiva ma più dispregiativa che negativa. Pensa per esempio ad omaccio o donnaccia la connessione ad un mondo volgare e rude e lampante, oppure a "figaccio" in questo caso il lato rude è visto come un qualcosa di positivo....

Comment: Volevo far notare che, in alcuni casi, l'aggiunta di tale suffisso può portare ad uno stravolgimento totale del significato di una parola. Un esempio che viene molto naturale al riguardo è quello del nome "foca", l'animale, che diventa "focaccia", l'alimento. *De gustibus non disputandum est*, ma credo di andare abbastanza sul sicuro dicendo che, in questo caso, non si abbia affatto una connotazione negativa.

Comment: @Phoenix87 Vero, ma *focaccia* non viene da *foca*, quindi quello che è corretto dire è che non tutte le parole che terminanno in -accio sono derivate da parole semplici con aggiunta di suffisso, alcune nascono invece proprio così.

Answer (score 3):

beh, non è proprio sempre negativo: se dico "questo film non era malaccio", oltre che fare una litote, intendo che il film è bello (e "male" non è un sostantivo, nell'esempio: pensa a "questo film era inguardabile").

Per il resto, il De Mauro fa derivare il suffisso dal latino *-aceu(m)* che però ha un altro significato che rimane in alcuni residui anche in italiano, come "strofinaccio / legaccio" (quindi si parte da un verbo e si crea un sostantivo per indicare la funzione) o banalmente per indicare una relazione spesso accrescitiva (gli esempi del De Mauro sono "beccaccia, gallinaccio, catenaccio": quest'ultimo non è una brutta catena ma una catena più robusta)

Comment: Sì, è vero, "malaccio" ha un sapore simpatico e benevolo, però è difficile dire che "non è malaccio" equivalga a "bene" o, come nel caso citato, a "bello", though.